# Listening to state changes when a property value is changed in a service

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I have a class / service in my Blazor MAUI application that regularly manipulates the data that is stored within it. There is an internal schedular on a fixed interval that regenerates the value.

I have a Blazor component that reads the value from this service. When the value changes in my service, I would like my Blazor component to reflect that change.

Just to keep it simple, lets take the following:

```
public class EmployeeService {
    
    public int NumberOfEmployees { get; private set; }

    public EmployeeService() {
        // Logic to initialize a fixed scheduled for function
        // RecalculateNumberOfEmployees();
    }

    private async void RecalculateNumberOfEmployees() {
        numberOfEmployees += 1;
    }
}
```

```
@path "/employees"
@inject EmployeeService Service

Number of employees: @Service.NumberOfEmployees

@code {
    
}
```

I found a recommendation [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-is-blazor-ui-notified-when-the-property-value-is-changed) that uses a timer to invoke `StateHasChanged()` but I really, really don't like that approach. It seems like it is a waste of resources and an anti-pattern.

My next step is to make `EmployeeService` accept `EventCallback` from the Blazor component and store that in a list. This would allow any component to *listen* for changes in the `EmployeeService` class. When a component is unmounted, it will delete the callback.

Something like:

**EmployeeService.cs**

```
    public List<EventCallback> listeners { get; private set; } = new List<EventCallback>();

    public async void RegisterCallback(EventCallback callback) {
        listeners.ForEach(...notify listeners);
    }

    public async void DeregisterCallback(EventCallback callback) {
        listeners.Remove ... etc
    }
```

**Employees.razor**

```
...

@code {

    // register / deregister callback and listen for changes, invoke StateHasChanged()

}
```

Before I go down this route, are there any better design patterns that I could use for future components that would be better suited for this purpose? I feel like this is something that should already be baked into the framework but haven't seen anything that addresses it.

Comment: See my answer to this question on how to notify Components from services - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an event Action:

**EmployeeService.cs**

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    public int NumberOfEmployees { get; private set; }

    public EmployeeService() {
        // Logic to initialize a fixed scheduled for function
        // RecalculateNumberOfEmployees();
    }

    private async void RecalculateNumberOfEmployees() {
        numberOfEmployees += 1;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
    
    public event Action OnChange;
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

**Employees.razor**

```
@inject EmployeeService EmployeeService
@implements IDisposable

Number of employees: @EmployeeService.NumberOfEmployees

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EmployeeService.OnChange += OnChangeHandler;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        EmployeeService.OnChange -= OnChangeHandler;
    }

    private async void OnChangeHandler()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use the Event Aggregator pattern. Take a look at this library:
https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.EventAggregator

Comment: Do you know if a circuit disconnection triggers Dispose?

Comment: I am getting `The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state` on the `NotifyStateChange()` definition.

Comment: You need to use InvokeAsync to execute StateHasChanged on the UI thread. Updated my answer, also check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477829/how-to-fix-the-current-thread-is-not-associated-with-the-renderers-synchroniza

Comment: The .NET naming convention is for the `On*` method to raise events and not the actual events themselves nor the event handlers. So and `OnChange` would raise the event in the `EmployeeService` class. `Change` would be the name of the event and `EmployeeService_Change` would typically be the name of the handler.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are probably right buy they didn't use this naming convention the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm. Edited my answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thank you good sir! Works like a charm. Does this work if there are multiple "listeners"?

Comment: Yes, it works with multiple listeners.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - That's horrible. So much for clear standards.

Comment: @Enigmativity: So much for clear standards. Do you mean the naming of events by Microsoft, as for instance, calling the `change` event `onchange`, the `click` event `onclick`, and so forth. Microsoft has been using event names with `on` for ages now.

Comment: @enet - Yes, but against their own standards.